# Get a role with discord.py

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

I'm trying to get a user's role to execute a command:

```
async def clear (ctx, n):
    if "Mod" in [y.name.lower() for y in ctx.message.author.roles]:
       //delete messages
    else:
       client.send_message(ctx.message.channel, "You are not allowed to use this command!")
```

When a normal user uses `!clear`, he can clear the messages, but also get the permission error.

Code:

```
@bot.command(pass_context=True)
async def clear(ctx, n):
   if "mod" in [y.name.lower() for y in ctx.message.author.roles]:
       n = int(n)
       tn = n + 1
       async for x in bot.logs_from(ctx.message.channel, limit=tn):
          await bot.delete_messages(x)

          await bot.send_message(ctx.message.channel, "Deleted" + str(n) + "messages")
   elif not "mod" in [y.name.lower() for y in ctx.message.author.roles]:
       await bot.send_message(ctx.message.channel, "You need the **Mod** role to use this command!")
```

When a normal user uses `!clear`, he can clear the messages, but also get the permission error.

**SOLUTION:**

```
@bot.command(pass_context=True)
async def clear(ctx, n):
   if "mod" in [y.name.lower() for y in ctx.message.author.roles]:
       n = int(n)
       msg = []
       tn = n + 1
       async for x in bot.logs_from(ctx.message.channel, limit=tn):
          msg.append(x)
          await bot.delete_messages(x)

       await bot.send_message(ctx.message.channel, "Deleted" + str(n) + "messages")
   elif not "mod" in [y.name.lower() for y in ctx.message.author.roles]:
       await bot.send_message(ctx.message.channel, "You need the **Mod** role to use this command!")
```

Comment: How can "Mod" with a capital letter ever match `name.lower()`? I'd be surprised if the delete messages *ever* ran really...

Comment: it happens the same thing with "mod" @squaswin

Comment: Can you please edit your post the whole function, this issue is a product of code other than what you have sent. If a normal user is getting the error message *and* can delete the messages, it means the call to delete isnt actually inside that if block...

Comment: I added the whole command

Comment: Not the issues causing your bug, but 1: Why are you calling bulk delete (`delete_messages`) inside a for loop, 2: What is that `break` doing, 3: Its going to send `"Deletednmessages"` every message it deletes, And there is still the issue that "Mod" with a capital will never exist in a list of lowercase names, so that code shouldn't ever actually run...

Comment: I'd suggest checking out [`purge_from`](http://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Client.purge_from) in the docs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Users that have the Mod role also have at least the @everyone role. So you need to change the `else` to `elif not "Mod" in [y.name.lower() for y in ctx.message.author.roles]:`.

Comment: That is just the logical cause of the else statement though... It doesn't matter what roles the user has, if "mod" isnt the name of one of them, the if block shouldnt be running at all.

Comment: With that I get the permission error with the "mod" role